# rel=0 on embedded YouTube video not working?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

Currently, I am developing a web-page where I am showing a list of videos by making usage of the YouTube-API. When a user clicks on one of the videos, it will open a new page with that embedded video on it.

To have the embedded video looking and acting as I want, I am using the following code (written in TypeScript):

```
  private generateInstructionVideoUrl(): void {
    this.currentInstructionVideoSource = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.instructionVideoId + "?rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&mute=0&showinfo=0&color=white&controls=1&autoplay=1&vq=hd1080&enablejsapi=1";
  }
```

This basically works exactly as how I expected it to work, however, I am facing one single problem.

I have added rel=0 to the embedded video URL, but it does not show related videos for me.

Does someone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Am I missing a YouTube setting?

Side note: on our YouTube channel we have about 9 public videos and 16 private videos.

Comment: 4

rel=0 is used to disable related videos shown at the end of a video, not to remove the suggested videos in the sidebars.  you can use the embed URL to access the video on its own - http://youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ. Add ?rel=0 to disable the related videos at the end too.

Comment: Hello @MehrajKhan. The Youtube docs tell me the following: If the parameter's value is set to 1, which is the default value, then the player does show related videos.
If the parameter's value is set to 0, then the player does not show related videos.
After the change, you will not be able to disable related videos. Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will come from the same channel as the video that was just played. --> Since September 25, 2018 it should show video's from the same channel if rel = 0. However, it does not do that for me.